# carrierwave_backgrounder initiliazer causing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm trying to get carrierwave set up with carrierwave_backgrounder, delayed_job, and fog for storage on AWS S3.

Whenever I try to do anything in the console such as generate controllers, I am getting this error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/carrierwave_backgrounder-0.0.9/lib/carrierwave_backgrounder.rb:19:in `backend': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
```

The culprit seems to be my initializer file, backgrounder.rb, which is copied directly from the carrierwave_backgrounder github.

```
CarrierWave::Backgrounder.configure do |c|
  # :delayed_job, :girl_friday, :sidekiq, :qu, :resque, or :qc
  c.backend :delayed_job 
end
```

If I comment that out, my generators and such start working. I set up delayed_job and carrierwave properly I believe. Here's my gemfile as well:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

gem 'pg'


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'devise'    
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder'
gem 'fog'
gem 'rmagick'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use latest git release for implement this.

Add this in your gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave_backgrounder', :git => "git://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder.git"
```